# Django 1.11.23 - calling superclass methods in a script

Tags: django-models

I'm exporting data from a legacy Django application and have written a script that imports the old models.py, which are something like this:

```
class GeneralType(models.Model):
    ...
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, blank=True)

class Publication(models.Model):
    ...
    authors = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)

class Record(GeneralType):
   ...
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

So, this should work:

```
for r in Record.objects.all():
    for p in r.publications.all():  # Exception thrown here
        print(p.url)
```

But instead it gives:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'generaltype' into field. Choices are: authors, url
```

So, there's some issue with calling GeneralType methods on a Record instance, presumably related to having abstracted this out to a script, as everything is fine if similar code is run in the Django app. 
There's probably something obvious I've missed here - would happen to know what it is?

Comment: where do you run this script, and with what command?

Comment: In a separate directory from the application (the model definitions are imported into the script), with the command `python ./script.py`